# Angular TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I have such div tag in my html file:

```html
<div *ngIf="chat.asReceiver.id != user?.id; else otherParty">
```

and it always return this error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

I have multiple times tested my variables and both `chat.asReceiver.id` and `user?.id` have values, then I put my div under `*ngIf` like:

```html
<div *ngIf="user">
   <div *ngIf="chat.asReceiver.id != user?.id; else otherParty">
      //....
   </div>
</div>
```

Still error exist.

`component`

```
public user: User;
chats: any[] = [];

constructor( ) {
    this.getChats();
}

ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.authService.user().subscribe(
      user => {
        this.user = user;
      }
    );
}

getChats() {
    this.privateChatService.getChats().subscribe((res) => {
      for (const chat of res.data) {
        this.chats.push(chat);
      }
    });
}
```

**Any idea?**

## Update

how my data look like

[image: one]

## Update 2

```
<div *ngIf="chats.length>0">
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let chat of chats; index as indexOfelement;">
        <div *ngIf="chat.asReceiver.id != user?.id; else otherParty">
            <ion-item class="chat-groups">
                <ion-avatar slot="start">
                <div *ngIf="chat.asReceiver.photo != null; else placeholderImage">
                    <img (click)="openImageRes(chat)" class="gImage" routerDirection="forward" [src]="chat.asReceiver.photo">
                </div>
                <ng-template #placeholderImage>
                    <img routerDirection="forward" class="gImage" src="../../assets/placeholders/avatar.jpg">
                </ng-template>
                </ion-avatar>
                <ion-label routerDirection="forward" [routerLink]="['/tabs/', 'chat', chat.id]">
                    <h2 style="float: left;width: 80%;"slot="start" [innerHTML]="chat.asReceiver.username"></h2>
                    <ion-badge slot="end" color="primary">{{totalBadges}}</ion-badge>
                </ion-label>
            </ion-item>
        </div>
    </ion-item-sliding>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the property `asReceiver` of the object `chat` does not exist.
In your provided code you do not show the definition of `chat`, can you please post it, too? Without exactly knowing what it is, you can try to add the question marks to the `ngIf` also for the chat.

```html
<div *ngIf="chat?.asReceiver?.id !== user?.id; else otherParty">
```

The problem here is that you also go into the else statement if both ids are undefined, not only if they are equal.

Comment: exactly, logic is if receiver id == logged user id show A else show B

Comment: Thanks! And how exactly do you get `chat` from your code snippet?

Comment: `<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let chat of chats; index as indexOfelement;"> // here is my loop in question </ion-item-sliding>`

Comment: I see, so chat is defined in every case, otherwise there wouldn't be the loop. Some of the chats seem not to have an existing `asReceiver` property. Can you check that please? Does the error appear with the questionmarks (I do not mean unexpected behavior, just the error)?

Comment: currently building new app with your solution to see if it works, will keep you posted when it's done

Comment: that worked thanks, also there was issue in my socket data which was looping 1 step before chat data, your code + my socket fix = solved ;) thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use something like

```
<div *ngIf="(chat && chat.asReceiver && user) && (chat.asReceiver.id !== user?.id); else otherParty">
```

Also, I would suggest rewriting everything using async pipes